# Is there a word for when someone's actions determine your life?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, terminology

So in my story, the main character's mom had this boyfriend (he was this typically cliche bad boy) but they broke up and the mom obviously ended up marrying someone else via dad. But this boyfriend was stuck up on her like Snape in Harry Potter and he had a son and that son felt like his father was deprived of him because the father was heart-broken after years still and still loved 'mom'. So this son seeks revenge on 'mom' and her family. Killing basically all except for the main character- but he's out for her next.

I don't have a title for this yet, and I was thinking of a title that means when your parents' actions or past affects you. Or anyone's actions really. Like when someone's mistakes/past/actions/decisions affect someone's whole life.

Comment: You seem to be talking of the ***life-changing influences*** of other people in your life.

Comment: Please provide a sentence into which such a word would be placed.

Comment: Hi Brionna, I see you've included the [tag:word-choice] tag. If you hover your mouse over the tag, you'll find a small write-up about it. Please check whether this tag is appropriate. If so, please provide the selection of words you're asking the community to choose from; if not, please delete that tag. You can do this via the [edit] link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea, hope it helps

If we think that the actions are elements of a system, the history itself, then you have that the actions will always affect one character life events.

Assuming that, we can say that you have a deterministic nonlinear system, hence you might think in the "butterfly effect" that's used to describe changes in that kind of systems.

Kind regards!!

Answer (score 0):

I think **dependence** is the word you are looking for.

A variant these may work:

- dependence
- depending on somebody
- depending on someone's mistakes/past/actions/decisions
- depending on the events in the life of somebody
- depending on the life of somebody

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be critical. I hope the admin will allow me saying so but that is one long confusing sentence.

Where you lose me is "that son felt like his father was deprived of him". Who felt what again? The motivations of all and sundry are still not clear.

A single word that could describe what you want is *Doomed*. The actions of those people in the past have *doomed* me to my current fate.

Others might say that the actions have *inexorably* caused my current fate.

If you please you might make three separate sentences out of your first one. Thank you.